# Autoscale AWS Lambda concurrency based off throttling errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, autoscaling

I have a AWS Lambda function using an AWS SQS trigger to pull messages, process them with an AWS Comprehend endpoint, and put the output in AWS S3. The AWS Comprehend endpoint has a rate limit which goes up and down throughout the day based off something I can control. The fastest way to process my data, which also optimizes the costs I am paying for the AWS Comprehend endpoint to be up, is to set concurrency high enough that I get throttling errors returned from the api. This however comes with the caveat, that I am paying for more AWS Lambda invocations, the flip side being, that to optimize the costs I am paying for AWS Lambda, I want 0 throttling errors.

Is it possible to set up autoscaling for the concurrency limit of the lambda such that it will increase if it isn't getting any throttling errors, but decrease if it is getting too many?

Comment: Maybe because I don't know AWS Comprehend I'm not understanding the issue. Why does having throttling errors give you the fastest way to process your data? Doesn't mean some of the data going through the lambda is delayed?

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting use case.

Let me start by pointing out something that I found out the hard way in an almost 4 hour long call with AWS Tech Support after being puzzled for a couple days.

With SQS acting as a trigger for AWS Lambda, the concurrency cannot go beyond 1K. Even if the concurrency of Lambda is set at a higher limit.

There is now a detailed [post](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-sqs-scaling/#:%7E:text=When%20you%20configure%20an%20SQS,maximum%20of%201%2C000%20concurrent%20invocations.) on this over at Knowledge Center.

With that out of the way and assuming you are under 1K limit at any given point in time and so only have to use one SQS queue, here is what I feel can be explored:

Either use an existing cloudwatch metric (via Comprehend) or publish a new metric that is indicative of the load that you can handle at any given point in time. you can then use this to set an appropriate concurrency limit for the lambda function. This would ensure that even if you have SQS queue flooded with messages to be processed, lambda picks them up at the rate at which it can actually be processed.

**Please Note:** This comes out of my own philosophy of being proactive vs being reactive. I would not wait for something to fail to trigger other processes eg invocation errors in this case to adjust concurrency. System failures should be rare and actually raise alarm (if not panic!) rather than being normal that occurs a couple of times a day !

To build up on that, if possible I would suggest that you approach this the other way around i.e. scale Comprehend processing limit and AWS Lambda concurrency based on the messages in the SQS queue (backlog) or a combination of this backlog and the time of the day etc. This way, if every part of your pipeline is a function of the amount of backlog in the Queue, you can be rest assured that you are not spending more than you have at any given point in time.

More importantly, you always have capacity in place should the need arise or something out of normal happens.